# Proper non-Stack Exchange site to ask about suggesting films by some topic

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Movies & TV Stack Exchange post: [searching for films by contents about challenges of seeing the world as your mirror](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/110031/searching-for-films-by-contents-about-challenges-of-seeing-the-world-as-your-mir)

I have the above question and have also asked about which SE site to ask about film suggestions, which was answered like this:

[image]

I saw the Movies.SE site tour before asking the question, and think this kind of question would come under the **Questions relating to the film and TV industry** category:

[image]

So while I don't know why I cannot ask that question here, I would like to know **what other sites are more proper for asking this kind of question**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To try and explain why recommendation questions are off-topic: questions on Stack Exchange should ideally have a single "correct" answer. This isn't the case with recommendation questions, as depending on the criteria, there could be hundreds or even thousands of films that match what you're looking for.

With that aside: the [r/MovieSuggestions](https://www.reddit.com/r/MovieSuggestions/) Reddit community looks like a good place to try. They accept "requests" of the sort that you want to make. I've never posted there myself, so I can't say how good their suggestions will be, but they do at least appear to be active.

[TasteDive](https://tastedive.com/movies) and [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls048796591/) are useful for finding movies based on broader criteria, such as "films set in prisons" or "satirical films". Your criteria are very specific, so I'm unsure how much help those sites will be to you, but they're worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks, i will test those site, as soon as possible.